# Why should we extend the radio antenna to make it work though we board on enough height?

Tags: radio, antennas

The old FM radios have an antenna to receive radio frequencies and work on them. If I am in ground floor, I have to extend or spread the antenna to make the radio work. Now if I go to the first or second floor, still then I have to extend the antenna. Why the radio does not work there with the antenna closed or not extended ?

Comment: You presumably think the radio signal should be so much stronger on the first or second floor that you don't need the aerial. Since you do need the aerial the obvious conclusion is that the radio signal is **not** that much stronger on the first and second floors.

Comment: Okay, but how the radio signal gets stronger by extending the antenna ?

Answer (score 2):

The reception of an em wave by an antenna is greatly enhanced if the length of the antenna is in some way related to the wavelength of the em wave.  It is a resonance effect.
So for a whip antenna the best reception is when the length of the antenna is slightly less than a quarter of a wavelength and for a dipole it should be slightly less than half a wavelength.

The fm signal is probably polarised and so it is worth trying see the difference between having the antenna horizontal and vertical or possibly somewhere in between.

Antennas are also directional and so it is worth rotating a horizontal antenna in the horizontal plane and find a position where the signal is weakest and then rotate the antenna through 90 degrees.

All in all you are trying to pick up a weak signal as efficiently as possible.